# Avoid cartesian product in three tables using LEFT join

Tags: mysql, join

I have following 3 tables:-

1. customers (customer_id, name)
2. achived (achived_id, customer_id, achieved)
3. target (target_id, customer_id, target)

On writing the following query, I am getting wrong output due to cartesian product:-

```
SELECT C.name customer, SUM(A.achieved) achived, SUM(T.target) target
FROM customers C
LEFT JOIN achieved A
ON C.customer_id = A.customer_id
LEFT JOIN target T
ON C.customer_id = T.customer_id 
GROUP BY customer
```

What would be the right approach of getting correct result using LEFT join?

Comment: wrong output  in the sense?

Comment: what is your expected output? provide a sqlfiddle.com link with your schema and sample data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this also...

```
SELECT C.name customer, SUM(A.achieved) achived, SUM(T.target) target
FROM customers C,achieved A,target T
WHERE C.customer_id = A.customer_id 
      AND C.customer_id = T.customer_id 
      AND A.customer_id = T.customer_id
GROUP BY C.customer
```

Comment: This does not produce the same result as a left join; it will exclude customers that do not have any target or achived (sic) records.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that, because you are joining `achieved` and `target` **both** onto `customer`, you are getting a meaningless cartesian product of `achieved` and `target`.

You can remove `SUM` for a moment to see the cause of the problem.
Without `SUM`, this query gives you a needlessly large result set. *With* `SUM`, the repeated values all contribute to the sum, creating a value larger than expected.

You can force MySQL to keep the joined tables apart *by joining a constant sequence*, as follows.

```
SELECT C.name customer, SUM(A.achieved) achieved, SUM(T.target) target

FROM customers C

# Split every customer into two rows, joinType=1 vs. joinType=2
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 AS joinItem UNION ALL SELECT 2) AS joinItems
ON TRUE

# Join achieved only where joinType=1 (will be NULL elsewhere)
LEFT JOIN achieved A
ON joinItem = 1 AND C.customer_id = A.customer_id

# Join target only where joinType=2 (will be NULL elsewhere)
LEFT JOIN target T
ON joinItem = 2 AND C.customer_id = T.customer_id 

GROUP BY customer
```

Now, achieved and target will no longer be multiplied with each other.

`EXPLAIN` should confirm that this is still handled efficiently.

*Note: Initially, this creates a customer record per matching 'achieved' (with 'target' data NULL), plus a separate customer record per matching 'target' (with 'achieved' data NULL). Then, however, the `GROUP BY` in this scenario reunites them back into a single record per customer, with exactly the data we want.*

Comment: is there a way to exclude NULL and print the records in case of NOT GROUP BY

Comment: @user1720827 If there's no inherent reason to use `GROUP BY`, we can still flatten the result set into something more natural. Initially each customer may appear twice, once with `achieved` null and once with `target` null. Use `GROUP BY customer` to combine the row pairs, and then use `MAX(A.achieved)` and `MAX(T.target)` to take the non-null value for each column. (To instead include multiple rows from `A` and `T`, consider joining only their IDs at first, applying this trick to the IDs, and then joining further data.)